# Count query stops working correctly after I add a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: problems, categories, and a joining table for problem_categories

I am trying to get and count all the categories associated with a problem, and count how many problems are associated with each problem.

Here is my query which doesn't return correct results:

```
SELECT 
  category_name , 
  categories.category_id , 
  problems.problem_id, 
  COUNT(problems.problem_id) as num_problems 
FROM 
  problem_categories 
left JOIN 
  categories 
on 
  problem_categories.category_id = categories.category_id 
left join 
  problems 
on
  problem_categories.problem_id = problems.problem_id 
WHERE 
  problem_categories.problem_id = 266
GROUP BY 
  problems.problem_id , category_name
```

but as soon as I take out the where clause, it returns all the categories and correct counts of problems.  But the trick is that I need to query this for a particular problem_id

Any way to adjust this query to get it right?  What am I doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you need to use the USING() function

Comment: @Chibuzo how and where? :) I have not really used it before.

Comment: Try moving the condition into `having` clause (after the `group by`): remove `where`, and add `having problems.problem_id = 266` at the end.

Comment: Please learn to use your shift key to use consistent upper/lower case in your SQL. The mix between UPPER and lower case for keywords makes reading it quickly become annoying. :) A little effort to format it for readability helps, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just tried it and it didn't do the trick.

Comment: I am actually surprised that it works at all when you are grouping by problem_id AND then counting it... I would expect 1 as result.

Comment: are you trying to find how many categories are associated with your problem and then find number of problems associated with each such category ?

Comment: @A.J.I am trying to find out what categories are associated with that problem, and how many problems in total are associated with each of those categories.  Exactly like the tags feature works on the top-right of this page of Stack Overflow :)

Comment: okay now I got what you want ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear. How can you count problems if you are selecting a specific one? If you want to count categories associated with a particular problem you do this (I am assuming you have foreign keys and no duplicates in the problem_categories table):

```
SELECT problem_id, COUNT(category_id) as num_categories
FROM problem_categories
WHERE problem_id = 266
GROUP BY problem_id
```

then join to problem table if you need to print out more problem information (for efficiency, always get the detail last). If you are wanting to count problem -> category -> problem then do:

```
select p1.problem_id, (COUNT(DISTINCT(p2.problem_id)) - 1) as num_problems
FROM
(select problem_id, category_id FROM problem_categories where problem_id = 266) as p1
inner join 
(select problem_id, category_id FROM problem_categories) as p2
ON p1.category_id = p2.category_id
GROUP by p1.problem_id
```

Again if you want to show the problem details, join to the problem table to get them. If you want the num_problems and num_categories together join the first query to the second one before joining to the problem table to get the problem detail. i.e.:

```
SELECT p1.problem_id, p1.num_categories, p2.num_problems 
FROM
(SELECT problem_id, COUNT(category_id) as num_categories
FROM problem_categories
WHERE problem_id = 266
GROUP BY problem_id) as p1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p1.problem_id, (COUNT(DISTINCT(p2.problem_id)) - 1) as num_problems
FROM
(SELECT problem_id, category_id FROM problem_categories where problem_id = 266) as p1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT problem_id, category_id FROM problem_categories) as p2
ON p1.category_id = p2.category_id
GROUP by p1.problem_id) as p2
ON p1.problem_id = p2.problem_id
```

Comment: totally confusing :) I pasted your second query and it returned errors about the ON p1.category = p2.category line.

Comment: If my original question was confusing, here is a rephrase that I think works: I am trying to find out what categories are associated with that problem, and how many problems in total are associated with each of those categories. Exactly like the tags feature works on the top-right of this page of Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I fixed the typo (I had category instead of category_id).

Comment: So working off your Stack Overflow example, you would be trying to count the number of questions associated with mysql and the number of other tags associated with mysql questions (e.g. linux, java etc.)? If yes, joining query one and two together gives you the answer.

Comment: could you please post how you'd join those two queries? Its getting complicated and I am not sure exactly how to get it right.  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Error error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE problem_id = 266) as p1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p1.problem_id, (COUNT(DISTINCT(' at line 6

Comment: If you want to show details on categories associated with a problem that would be a different query (unless you perhaps want to concatenate all the category names into one string separated by a separator like ",").

Comment: The last query you had a problem with (both one and two together)?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p1.problem_id, problem_categories.category_id , category_name , 
    COUNT(*) as num_problems 
FROM problems p1
LEFT JOIN problem_categories  on
   p1.problem_id = problem_categories.problem_id 
LEFT JOIN categories on 
   problem_categories.category_id = categories.category_id 
LEFT JOIN problems p2 ON
   p2.problem_id = problem_categories.problem_id 
WHERE p1.problem_id = 266
GROUP BY categories.category_id,p2.problem_id
ORDER BY categories.category_id
```

Thats it

Comment: nope, that still didn't work and gave the same wrong result as I had :)

Comment: Does it work having p2.problem_id in the group by  (and you don't need, but it doesn't hurt, to have p1; also you can use inner joins, since you can be assured that you will always have at least 1 problem for each category that matches the categories of problem 266, that is, problem 266 itself)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN problems p2 ON` sure there you can use `INNER JOIN`. p1 you dont need in the group by it is always 266 .. but it would not hurt..

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work:

```
SELECT category_name , categories.category_id, COUNT(*) as num_problems 
FROM problem_categories src JOIN CATEGORIES ON src.category_id = categories.category_id 
    JOIN problem_categories dest ON categories.category_id = dest.category_id 
WHERE problems.problem_id = 266
GROUP BY categories.category_id
```

What you are doing is for the problem id you want you look up the categories ids and from there the names, and from categories id you look how many (if any) problems each has.
The non usage of the problem table is intentional. Also, for this to perform you need to index the problem_categories in BOTH orders.

UPDATE: The Left join can be an inner join, because each category related to problem 266 has at least one problem (problem 266).

Answer (score 1):

you can prepare the categories and the count of problems in them. after that you can use it as part of any query to supply info.

```
SELECT categories.category_name ,
       categories.category_id,
       (select COUNT(*)
        from problem_categories
        where problem_categories.category_id =categories.category_id
       ) as num_problems
FROM categories
```

that can be used in a join (and if you wish stored in a temporary table) to supplement info about the categories:

```
select problem_categories.problem_id,
       temp_tab.category_name ,
       temp_tab.category_id,
       temp_tab.num_problems            
from problem_categories, 
(
SELECT categories.category_name ,
       categories.category_id,
       (select COUNT(*)
        from problem_categories
        where problem_categories.category_id =categories.category_id
       ) as num_problems
FROM categories 
) temp_tab
where problem_categories.problem_id =266
and problem_categories.category_id = temp_tab.category_id
```

if you will use this with more than one id or without the id condition, it is better to store the info from the category in a temporary table and join it in order not to repeat the calculations.